# How to have Windows 7 index Thunderbird 3 messages?

Tags: windows-7, email, thunderbird, search

How can I have Windows 7 index my Thunderbird 3 email messages? 
According to [this article](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/14-new-features-in-thunderbird-3-that-will-make-you-rejoice/) (Dec. 2009), this should be possible.

> "Integration With Windows Search
>   (Windows 7/Vista)
>
> On first start, Thunderbird will
>   prompt you to install the indexing
>   system in Windows 7/Vista. This will
>   help index all emails in Windows
>   Search and allow users to see emails
>   and new messages in Windows search
>   results."

However, no messages are indexed, and I don't recall seeing any prompt when I installed the TB3 beta, or when I upgraded to the TB3 Release Candidate. I don't want to reinstall TB either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I found the answer myself:

Under Tools > Options > Advanced > General > System Integration there is a checkbox "Allow Windows Search to search messages".

After checking it, give Windows some time to index your email.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That quote is for Thunderbird 3 final, not the beta or release candidate.

You need to upgrade to Thunderbird 3 final for the intergration

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/14-new-features-in-thunderbird-3-that-will-make-you-rejoice/

> INTEGRATION WITH WINDOWS SEARCH (WINDOWS 7/VISTA)
>   On first start, Thunderbird will prompt you to install the indexing system in Windows 7/Vista. This will help index all emails in Windows Search and allow users to see emails and new messages in Windows search results.

Update: I believe you need to download and re-install Thunderbird 3, as this box will appear when installing, not starting up for the first time, actually installing the product

[image]

Comment: Ah, strange they added such an extra feature in the final release which was not present in the RC.  Also strange that if I do "check for updates" it doesn't update from RC to final...

Comment: Seems weird, but i have installed Thunderbird 3 and it works with Windows 7 perfectly

Comment: Hmm, the final version was now offered as an update when "check for updates", but after one day, no prompt nor indexing... :-(

Comment: So you now have TB 3 but still no indexing?

Comment: Reinstall, and even uninstall and reinstall didn't get me the prompt to show up. However, I just noticed that under Tools > Options > Advanced > General > System Integration there is now a checkbox "Allow Windows Search to search messages". I've checked it and will wait some time for the indexing to take place (noticed no indication of the indexing)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the above step, which was already enabled on my "Win 7" system.

You ALSO had to have the filetype:  wdseml    ...enabled

1. Go to your Start button (very bottom left corner)
2. Click on it, and enter "index" (w/o quotes) into the little "Search programs and files"
3. "Don't click" on the last. Just let it produce a list.
4. At/Near the top of the list, you should see "Indexing Options"
5. Click on that and then click on the "advanced tab"
6. Then click on "File Types"
7. Scroll down to "wdseml" and "check" it's box...
8. Click ok, etc.

Other: I've also set my search to do both "filenames and contents" though this takes longer in case "what I'm looking for is "like someone's name in an email or other file, etc.

You can do this in this "index options"